# Attribute to call OnPropertyChanged on WPF viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In the viewmodels of a wpf app I often need to declare properties like this:

```
 public string IdAnalisi5
  {
     get { return ricettaCorrente.IdAnalisi1; }
     set
     {
        ricettaCorrente.IdAnalisi5 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IdAnalisi5));
     }
  }
```

The class implements the OnPropertyChanged method to trigger the update of the ui, but most of the times I have just to call this method, and is a lot of repeated code.
Is it actually possibile to create an attribute I can add to all the classes implement a class or interface with that method that calls the method after I set the value?
I would like to convert to something like this

```
[PropertyChanged(nameof(IdAnalisi5)]
public string IdAnalisi5 => ricettaCorrente.IdAnalisi1;
```

Very often could save a lot of code.

Comment: I faced this problem couples years ago, I've solved it by using `dynamic proxy pattern` instead of using 'Attributes'. If you want i can write an answer for you.

Comment: thanks, could be interesting. I looked right now to this pattern: seems a bit overkill solution for a simple problem, but could be interesintg

Answer (score 1):

As I said I don't know a way to solve this by 'Attribute' but there are some implementation of dynamic proxy patterns to simplify usage of `OnPropertyChanged`.

**Creation of the proxy**

```
    public class ProxyCreator
{
  public static T MakeINotifyPropertyChanged<T>() where T : class, new ()
  {
    //Creates a proxy generator
    ProxyGenerator proxyGen = new  ProxyGenerator();
 
    //Generates a proxy using our Interceptor and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
    var proxy = proxyGen.CreateClassProxy(
      typeof (T),
      new  Type[] { typeof (INotifyPropertyChanged) },
      ProxyGenerationOptions.Default,
      new  NotifierInterceptor()
      );
 
    return proxy as T;
  }
}
```

**The interceptor** which does two main things :

It exposes a `PropertyChangedEventHandler`,
It raises the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` event when a setter is called with the good name. Also, It has cached the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` for better performance.

```
public class NotifierInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
  private PropertyChangedEventHandler handler;
  public static Dictionary<String, PropertyChangedEventArgs> _cache =
    new  Dictionary<string, PropertyChangedEventArgs>();
 
  public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
  {
    //Each subscription to the PropertyChangedEventHandler is intercepted (add)
    if (invocation.Method.Name == "add_PropertyChanged")
    {
      handler = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)
            Delegate.Combine(handler, (Delegate)invocation.Arguments[0]);
      invocation.ReturnValue = handler;
    }
    //Each de-subscription to the PropertyChangedEventHandler is intercepted (remove)
    else if (invocation.Method.Name == "remove_PropertyChanged")
    {
      handler = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)
         Delegate.Remove(handler, (Delegate)invocation.Arguments[0]);
      invocation.ReturnValue = handler;
    }
    //Each setter raise a PropertyChanged event
    else if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("set_"))
    {
      //Do the setter execution
      invocation.Proceed();
      //Launch the event after the execution
      if (handler != null)
      {
        PropertyChangedEventArgs arg =
          retrievePropertyChangedArg(invocation.Method.Name);
        handler(invocation.Proxy, arg);
      }
    }
    else invocation.Proceed();
  }
 
  // Caches the PropertyChangedEventArgs
  private PropertyChangedEventArgs retrievePropertyChangedArg(String methodName)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventArgs arg = null;
    NotifierInterceptor._cache.TryGetValue(methodName, out arg);
    if (arg == null)
    {
      arg = new  PropertyChangedEventArgs(methodName.Substring(4));
      NotifierInterceptor._cache.Add(methodName, arg);
    }
    return arg;
  }
}
```

And the at last **usage** is like:

```
MyBusinessObject myBusinessObject;
DataContext = myBusinessObject = ProxyCreator.MakeINotifyPropertyChanged<MyBusinessObject>();
```

And also i found other implementations of dynamic proxy that do the same:

[Implement InotifyPropertyChanged with Castle.DynamicProxy](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/04/implement-inotifypropertychanged-with-castledynamicproxy/)

I hope to be helpful for you:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MVVM Light Toolkit. You'll need to subclass your view model from `ViewModelBase`, and then you'll be able to write something like this:

```
public string IdAnalisi5
{
    get => ricettaCorrente.IdAnalisi5;
    set => Set(ref ricettaCorrente.IdAnalisi5, value);
}
```

Note that this only works if `ricettaCorrente.IdAnalysi5` is a field, not a property.

MVVM Light Toolkit is not the only tool that gives you this functionality. Other similar tools include Prism and Caliburn.Micro.